# Does laravel passport serialize entire user object in bearer token?

Tags: laravel, api

I am using laravel with passport and jensseger mongodb to create an API. All works well, but I notice that the bearer tokens I get from passport are very long. My question is wether passport stores the entire user object in the bearer token, or if Auth::user fetches the user from db by id only....

I have a model:

```
class User extends \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;
    protected $collection = 'db.users';
    protected $fillable = ['name','phone','email' ...];
  ......
}
```

I then use `$user->createToken('....')->accessToken` to generate tokens at login.

I then use `Auth::user()` to fetch current user from token internally.  Which all works, but the bearer tokens are very long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tokens are long because they have been base64 encoded.

Here is a random token I found on another SO question:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjgzYmQ5NmNkYWE1MWZhMTJlMzQ4OTEzYWNjOGQwNmMzMjE2YzQ0N2U3ZmQyOWQyYThiNmY1YjUwMzAzZWFlOGU4ZjE4ZjNhM2M4OGE4OGVkIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiODNiZDk2Y2RhYTUxZmExMmUzNDg5MTNhY2M4ZDA2YzMyMTZjNDQ3ZTdmZDI5ZDJhOGI2ZjViNTAzMDNlYWU4ZThmMThmM2EzYzg4YTg4ZWQiLCJpYXQiOjE1MzY5NjEyMjgsIm5iZiI6MTUzNjk2MTIyOCwiZXhwIjoxNTY4NDk3MjI4LCJzdWIiOiI1Iiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.Ev1S4MhkDwdNPMhFIbSNdTUnlK-C4CRiUIHEhBulkjy4rTCkAGVWX01DsAdkGa_SP2o7d9M5Yw71m1yo3FG1eNZriJHbeKfLVz78MaWrX9daITmPhgh8sGaF9JlASU0I3QmVO-hnX57QSFTvDfzBjS3ApDx-CUhPV9M7ycljzBoYwiQZHloBpxHVqaavN-9CQQEuaZf8MhRJ-dg2BPoEVHp5lUtsjtZUll4hztvkJO4uz_hth0bo_i7l7pyrcS811BPK1iLAWlmsjdpUziFxCEpVsVVBpO5I8N5SLwgfiEsfM9PuMQua4kkt7whDUzitPQCaPR6TaBifFZfy1Hi37TYenK3aGb8VrX5HbU6HmYeYeIx8lFcugRwktVtuAURoRSWrlAkcfyMRM1nraSBWO3XVLc8nDNtnx6UG3yEjTLeqrUamy43Y5a4wszLnE9iXiPVA0Ip-_Y7gKsL9uE9h523YtIO1nGCJVSg8jr7T1XKWGaTFssJf9E9T5rAmdIu-hbW9Tm2NVL1z0dINva_F6SLmUqWQ0c3Wl1mrHmH3VqEBFP5-FUWzw2hFj1agwLe_933i5UdLl1EHwUqFpr_cVjVj952Do8LzEAuL2LLfZo82kPTP-h5jdWaWmoH-tJ_xXuWoRD5Y9nCFm_6-zJJpR3kcgz3jLMUCu_VAgNWTtw0

Copy and paste that token into [here](https://jwt.io/#encoded-jwt).

**Header**

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "jti":"83bd96cdaa51fa12e348913acc8d06c3216c447e7fd29d2a8b6f5b50303eae8e8f18f3a3c88a88ed"
}
```

**Payload**

```
{
  "aud": "1",
  "jti": "83bd96cdaa51fa12e348913acc8d06c3216c447e7fd29d2a8b6f5b50303eae8e8f18f3a3c88a88ed",
  "iat": 1536961228,
  "nbf": 1536961228,
  "exp": 1568497228,
  "sub": "5",
  "scopes": []
}
```

The payload has the answer to your question, which is the `sub` - subject - claim. That represents the authenticated entity ID. So user ID 5.